# Redirect rules to ignore folder

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I want to redirect all URL's of the form:
https://example.com/foldername/friendlyurl
to
https://example.com/friendlyurl
How can this be done using a redirect rule in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<rule name="folderrule">
   <match url="(.*)(foldername/)(.*)" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" ignoreCase="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}{R:3}" />
</rule>
```